# Android scheduled notification not showing, after setting it up in Firebase console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am learning how to send periodic notification into my android app from my Firebase console:

*Homepage.java*:

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {            

  startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),firebase_connection.class)); 
 //Here I am calling the service class
        
}
```

---

*firebase_connection.java*:

```
public class firebase_connection extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage message) {
        super.onMessageReceived(message);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("MyNotifications","MyNotifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("electric").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                String msg = "Welcome to my app";
                if(!task.isSuccessful())
                    msg = "Sorry";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),msg,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

*My Firebase console*:

[This is my scheduled notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwxwq.png)

---

I kept waiting till 9:40 AM (as set in my notifications settings given int the above screenshot) and no notification showed up. I am new to Firebase, where am I going wrong? Please help me.

**I am running the app on an actual device**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bunch of stuff you are missing. Firstly, you have to declare `FirebaseMessagingService` inside `AndroidManifest` like this within `application` tag:

```
<service android:name=".firebase_connection">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

And instead of calling `startService` in `onCreate` method, you have to subscribe to topic. Right now, you are subscribing in the notification service itself which is completely wrong.

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {            
  FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("electric").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
       @Override
       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
           String msg = "Welcome to my app";
           if(!task.isSuccessful())
               msg = "Sorry";
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),msg,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   });
}
```

Finally, in the `FirebaseMessagingService`, you are just creating a notification channel but not creating a notification itself. Do it like this:

```
public class firebase_connection extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage message) {
        super.onMessageReceived(message);

        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("channel1","My Notification", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            channel.setDescription("description");
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Notification notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "channel1")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentTitle(message.getNotification().getTitle())
            .setContentText(message.getNotification().getBody())
            .build();

             manager.notify(1, notification)
        }
    }
}
```

And you can use `RemoteMessage` object to fetch the title and the text you sent from the Firebase Console like above. Hope it works out!